# Heroku H10 works on localhost, won't work in deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

This error seems to be pretty popular here! The app works great locally, but when deploying to Heroku... crickets, Application crashes.

This is server.js

```
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || process.env.REACT_APP_PORT;
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") ? app.use(express.static("build")) : app.use(express.static("public"));

//code goes here

app.use(cors());

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('api/tweets');
})

app.get('api/tweets', function (req, res) {
    tweetData.findOne({}, [], { $orderby : { 'created_at' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
        console.log(post);
        res.send(post);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("App running on port " + PORT);
});
```

This is log entry

```
2020-05-10T00:12:59.057966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quarantine-life.herokuapp.com request_id=bd00538a-e6c4-4d33-ab5b-957eca72146f fwd="68.173.68.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is the API call in App.js

```
  callTwitterApi = async () => {
    await axios.get(my_heroku_app_URL_goes_here)
      .then(res => {
          //pipeline length control
          if (this.state.count === 20){ 
            this.clearTweets();
          }
          //checking if the tweet is new
          this.checkIfNew(res.data);
      })
      .catch (error => {
        this.setState({ error, isLoading: true });
      })
      this.setState({isLoading: true, isNew: ""});
  }
```

Package.json:

```
`{
  "name": "quarantine-life",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.3",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-animated-css": "^1.2.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.0",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start & node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "proxy": "HEROKU_URL_GOES_HERE"
}
`
```

I've tried the following approaches

- proxy entry onto package.json
- middleware npm package
- ungodly amount of beer

Any help for this noob right here, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your Procfile and package.json

Comment: sure! thanks so much for getting back to me :) I've edited my op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check your buildpacks

Type this command:

```
heroku buildpacks
```

You should see the following:

```
1. heroku/nodejs
```

If no, you have to install it to overcome the H10 error:
 [Heroku buildpack for nodejs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs).

**----UPDATE----**

I've just noticed you used **create-react-app** to build your app.

Therefore, just install the needed buildpack to get rid of H10:

```
heroku buildpacks:set mars/create-react-app
```

Comment: yeap it's there :)

Comment: Have you compared the used node.js version on both local env and heroku?

Comment: Thanks! Trying it and letting you know how it goes :)

Comment: ok we have progress! I can see the page of my progress, however Axios doesn't fetch any data...

Comment: This is probably related to your own app configuration, check the effective destination URL of your axios call in production (heroku). For instance, letting "localhost" is a trivial and common clumsiness :)
Check for some eventual errors in your browser console.

Comment: Interesting! Since I'm fairly new -- how could I potentially check the effective destination URL? Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: You're welcome! 
Like I've just said above, check in your browser console for eventual errors that will help greatly :)

Comment: Yes I figured! I don't see anything in the console, but I'll try to dig deeper