# Why does Axios fetch the whole html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

After dealing with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705589/heroku-h10-works-on-localhost-wont-work-in-deployment) I came across another happy accident. When I call axios it fetches the whole page, instead of the data I'm trying to parse.

Here's a snippet on the front end (react):

```
callTwitterApi = async () => {
    await axios('https://domain_url/api/tweets')
      .then(res => {
        console.log("hitting the API");
        console.log(res.data);
          //pipeline length control
          if (this.state.count === 20){ 
            this.clearTweets();
          }
          //checking if the tweet is new
          this.checkIfNew(res.data);
      })
      .catch (error => {
        this.setState({ error, isLoading: true });
      })
      this.setState({isLoading: true, isNew: ""});
  }
```

and here's what happens on the backend (node, mongo):

```
app.get('/api/tweets', function (req, res) {
   tweetData.findOne({}, [], { $orderby : { 'created_at' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
        console.log(post);
        res.send(post);
    });
});
```

The thing is, axios fetches the whole html page and it gives me some bogus results in the Heroku log.

What I've tried so far:

- catch all approach 1: (app.get ('*',...)
- catch all approach 2: (app.get ('/',...)
- I also use Cors (just in case)

May I add that in local/dev environment it works like a charm? I am *confused*

Thank you in advance for all your help!

---UPDATE---
This is what axios fetches:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/twitter-logo-1.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"><title>#QuarantineLife</title><link href="/static/css/2.74189dbb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/static/css/main.ddd0a433.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,i,l=r[0],a=r[1],f=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<l.length;c++)i=l[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,i)&&o[i]&&s.push(o[i][0]),o[i]=0;for(n in a)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,n)&&(e[n]=a[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,f||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,l=1;l<t.length;l++){var a=t[l];0!==o[a]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=i(i.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function i(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,i),t.l=!0,t.exports}i.m=e,i.c=n,i.d=function(e,r,t){i.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},i.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},i.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=i(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(i.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)i.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},i.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return i.d(r,"a",r),r},i.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},i.p="/";var l=this["webpackJsonpquarantine-life"]=this["webpackJsonpquarantine-life"]||[],a=l.push.bind(l);l.push=r,l=l.slice();for(var f=0;f<l.length;f++)r(l[f]);var p=a;t()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.c37a2338.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.761fb0aa.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

And here are the latest Heroku logs

```
2020-05-12T00:19:12.416413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/tweets" host=quarantine-life.herokuapp.com request_id=e72d108e-b257-4c87-88df-50ed57a6605f fwd="100.38.162.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-05-12T00:19:12.418672+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.61.229 - - [12/May/2020:00:19:12 +0000] "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://quarantine-life.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2020-05-12T00:27:48.414092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/tweets" host=quarantine-life.herokuapp.com request_id=783dc451-766f-4907-97d7-25b66d2d826b fwd="100.38.162.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-05-12T00:27:48.413796+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.109.106 - - [12/May/2020:00:27:48 +0000] "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://quarantine-life.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2020-05-12T00:37:14.441515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/tweets" host=quarantine-life.herokuapp.com request_id=9a830269-3886-41d9-8657-33d567ab2109 fwd="100.38.162.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-05-12T00:37:14.449334+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.238.92 - - [12/May/2020:00:37:14 +0000] "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://quarantine-life.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2020-05-12T00:47:38.448235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/tweets" host=quarantine-life.herokuapp.com request_id=8a36715a-940a-4f23-97b9-4ee75b05cc4b fwd="100.38.162.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-05-12T00:47:38.448534+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.61.189.68 - - [12/May/2020:00:47:38 +0000] "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://quarantine-life.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2020-05-12T00:59:04.510471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/tweets" host=quarantine-life.herokuapp.com request_id=be86d0da-8bf9-4fb0-9d0d-6acfb08f0fc1 fwd="100.38.162.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-05-12T00:59:04.510335+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.71.246.139 - - [12/May/2020:00:59:04 +0000] "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://quarantine-life.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: If it return an html page, maybe it's an error page from your server. For examples some servers return 500 detailed html pages, for some server error. Have you tried to inspect the error message. Could you dump some of your error message here?

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me, I appreciate it! It's actually an html dump. 

`<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/twitter-logo-1.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"> `

Comment: it's not the message in its entirety of course - but just to give you a glimpse. Hope it's helpful

Comment: Try logging the error and the post of the server if you have access to the server logs. 
Something like... `tweetData.findOne({}, [], { $orderby : { 'created_at' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
        if(err){
console.error(err);
} else {
        console.log(post);
        res.send(post);
}
    });`
And could you add some mesction of the body tag?

Comment: I don't know how I can access the server logs on Heroku, but here's the body part (edited in OP) and Heroku logs (there, too)

Comment: I bet the problem is with one of your other route handlers.  Maybe a wildcard * route that returns the index.html.  And the request is going to that one instead of your intended route.

Comment: That's what I thought so too, however when I tried adding a:
`app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/api/tweets');`

or a 
`app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/api/tweets');`

it still didn't quite work :/